# Override a class method with keeping original class name and files (A cleaner way? - PHP/Joomla)

Tags: php, class, joomla, overriding

I know this method is far from clean, yet after many research it was the only thing working. The problem is that I cannot modify the original files, and i would like the class to have a method changed (not an instance, the whole class definition). The class name must not change for this to work with Joomla and the plugin i am using.

This override is made with a custom plugin. It means i could override the whole original file if i wanted to. But i would like to override only a single method, in order to get the best compatibility with the next plugin upgrades. It would keep all other methods from original class.

The problem was a bit hardened by the fact that this class also extends another class, which must stay in the global namespace for other extends elsewhere.

The method i found, it works but really ugly:

file 1 - the main overriden file replaced by:

```
//kept from original file, because its class must stay global
require_once(PLG_ROOT . '/parentClass.php');
//import the original class wrapped in a namespace
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/wrappedClass.php');

//overriding the method with inheritance from wrapped class
class FixedName extends \theSpace\FixedName
{
    public function iAmOverriden() { }
}
```

file 2 - original file imported in a dirty way in a namespace:

```
eval("namespace theSpace {
    //making the global parent class available in the space
    use \ParentName as ParentName;
    ?>" . file_get_contents(PLG_ROOT . '/originalClass.php') . '}');
```

This way, the file content from originalClass.php is able to create the class with inheritance from the parent, and i have no name conflict. But well, ugly, isn't it? Is there another way to do this in php?

Comment: It's not clear why you can't use "normal" inheritance here. Place your class in a new namespace so it can use the same class name, extend the parent class, and then modify the overridden method.
Not sure if it's a core class you're overriding but take a look here at the 2nd answer - https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/205/how-to-override-core-classes#207

Comment: @waterloomatt i can't modify either the parent and original class files as they are provided by another plugin that updates regularly. If i include the original class file in a namespace, the resulting class is global, because there is no namespace declaration in the original class file..

Comment: @waterloomatt thx for the link, but i have already done that (overriding a core file through a plugin), the thing is that it would force me to redefine the whole class, when i would like to change just one method.

Comment: But you don't need to redefine all methods in a class that you extend. Methods that are not defined in the subclass will be using the parent class definition.

Comment: thanks for the answer @jonasfh, unfortunately i am not using the classes myself, the component i am overriding does it. This mean i cannot extend original class to add or change a method, because its name would change and component would then use the original one (PHP sends error when trying to create a class that is already defined)